# Andriod NDK: SIGABRT when throwing c++ std::exception

Tags: c++, exception, android-ndk, java-native-interface, c++14

I'm struggling to surface native c++ exceptions up to Java.
I've tried std::runtime_error and std::exception but both make the process abort.

Some context:
I properly implemented JNI handling (but I don't even get there):

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_sdk_gateway_SetValue(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jfloat value)
{
    jint retCode = RETVALUE::ERR_FAILED;
    try
    {
        retCode = gateway::SetValue(value);
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error ex) // or catch(std::exception ex)
    { 
        // not even getting here in debug
        throwJavaException(env, ex.what());
    }

    return retCode;
}
```

My native compiler switches (LLVM):

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "gtaNativeCode"

    // add compilation flags
    cppFlags.add("-DANDROID")
    cppFlags.add("-frtti")
    cppFlags.add("-std=c++14")
    cppFlags.add("-fexceptions") // Enables exception-handling support.

    // include headers
    cppFlags.add("-I${file("native-src")}".toString())

    ldLibs.addAll("android", "dl", "log", "z", "atomic")

    // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html
    //stl = "gnustl_static"  // The GNU STL (static library). This is the default runtime when using CMake or a standalone toolchain.
    //stl = "stlport_static"
    stl = "c++_static"  // LLVM compiler
}
```

While in c++, I just throw exceptions as this simple pattern:

```
RETVALUE gateway::SetValue(float value)
{
    RETVALUE result = RETVALUE::ERR_FAILED;

    // doing some stuff

    if (0 != errno)
            throw std::runtime_error("error message"); // << SIGABRT as soon as the throw is executed 

    return result;
}
```

As soon as the throw is executed, I get the SIGABRT in Android Studio (v2.3.3, latest NDK).

I read all the other questions in the forum, but the only clue would be switching from "c++_static" to "gnustl_static" ("stl_port" doesn't support mutex, chrono & thread which I need), but unfortunately this cannot be an option in my case, since I have libraries with heavy use of std::string conversion functions (i.e.: to_string, strtold, stoi, etc.) that I cannot avoid using.

In any case, as per the official website (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html), "c++_static" DOES support exceptions, so can't justify why I should change (unless LLVM libc++ is buggy).

Could anyone please help me with some ideas?
Thanks

**>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>EDIT<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<**

As per suggestions, I moved the native compiling away from experimental gradle, into standard CMAKE.

Everything is working as before, but unfortunately the results are the same: as soon as I throw a C++ exception to be caught from JVM, the process aborts.

Here's my new gradle file (if it could also be of help to someone):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25

    externalNativeBuild {

        cmake {
            // Pass arguments to CMake
            arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                    "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE",
                    "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static",
                    "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"

            cppFlags "-frtti" // Enables RTTI support.
            cppFlags "-fexceptions" // Enables exception-handling support.
            cppFlags "-std=c++14"                
        }
    }

    // Similar to other properties in the defaultConfig block,
    // you can configure the ndk block for each product flavor
    // in your build configuration.
    ndk {

        moduleName "gtaNativeCode"
        abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'x86'
    }

    // If you want Gradle to package prebuilt native libraries
    // with your APK, modify the default source set configuration
    // to include the directory of your prebuilt .so files as follows.
    sourceSets.main {
        // C and C++ source code
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build
        jniLibs.srcDirs 'src/main/native'
    }
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'src/main/native/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

// This allows the library project to be built in debug mode, so we can actually debug it
publishNonDefault true
}

configurations {
    // Expose the debug version of the library to other modules
    debug
    release
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}
```

Comment: This is not using `externalNativeBuild`, right? You should probably try switching to either CMake or ndk-build. If this is the deprecated gradle plugin that could very well be the issue, since that isn't maintained and might just be linking libc++ incorrectly.

Comment: catch by `const &` or you risk slicing and other nastiness.

Comment: @RichardCritten thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Dan, nope, not using externalNativeBuild as you supposed... could you please point me into the right direction to implement on that path? Honestly, I just started up the native project through the wizard and just stuck to the gradle settings as is. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/

Comment: I edited my question, as I updated the build gradle to the standard non-experimental... unfortunately I still get a process abort as soon as I throw a native exception :(

Comment: @gtrevi, did you solve this?

Comment: @Robin unfortunately not, and still with the latest NDK... I regretfully adapted my C++ SDK to work alternatively without exceptions when compiling under Android (were a few through)... a true pity as all works in UWP, and btw with strait C++, which JNI does not support...